# TestEngine with ID 'cucumber' failed to discover tests, scenarios to run in Parallel on Azure Selfhosted Agent (Junit5+Cucumber7)

Tags: azure-devops, cucumber, junit5

Implemented (Junit5+ Cucumber7) parallelism on local machine using @Suite in RunCucumberTest ,'junit-platform.properties' which works as expected (Scenarios execute in parallel)
Need to get the same via Azure

For Azure created created a maven3 task yml
jobs:

- job: Default
  #strategy:
  #parallel: 3
  pool:
  name: 
  steps:

  - script: "PowerShell script to pull 3.9.0 maven>
  - task: ExtractFiles@1
  - task: Maven@3
  - Reporting`

POM

```
<cucumber. Version>7.6.0</cucumber. Version>
<versions.selenium>3.141.59</versions.selenium>
<webdrivermanager.version>5.2.1</webdrivermanager.version>
<junit.jupiter.version>5.9.2</junit.jupiter.version>`
<apache.common.version>2.4</apache.common.version>
<projectlombok.version>1.18.24</projectlombok.version>
<maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.9.0</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
<maven.surefire.plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</maven.surefire.plugin.version>
<maven.compiler.source.version>11</maven.compiler.source.version>
<maven.compiler.target.version>11</maven.compiler.target.version>
<extentreports.cucumber7.adapter.version>1.7.0</extentreports.cucumber7.adapter.version>`

Getting below error
2023-03-31T15:57:19.3274612Z [INFO] 
2023-03-31T15:57:19.3275096Z [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
2023-03-31T15:57:19.3275475Z [INFO]  T E S T S
2023-03-31T15:57:19.3275840Z [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
2023-03-31T15:57:20.9433301Z Mar 31, 2023 3:57:20 PM io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.DiscoverySelectorResolver warnWhenCucumberFeaturesPropertyIsUsed
2023-03-31T15:57:20.9434362Z WARNING: Discovering tests using the cucumber.features property. Other discovery selectors are ignored!
2023-03-31T15:57:20.9434898Z Please request/upvote/sponsor/ect better support for JUnit 5 discovery selectors.
2023-03-31T15:57:20.9435345Z See: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/pull/2498
2023-03-31T15:57:20.9445927Z [ERROR] TestEngine with ID 'cucumber' failed to discover tests
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0115930Z [INFO] 
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0116351Z [INFO] Results:
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0116609Z [INFO] 
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0145329Z [INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0146137Z [INFO] 
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0231640Z [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0232137Z [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0232407Z [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0249036Z [INFO] Total time:  26.828 s
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0251112Z [INFO] Finished at: 2023-03-31T15:57:21Z
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0251451Z [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0260708Z [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M7:test (default-test) on project MTH_SF_CRM: 
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0261269Z [ERROR] 
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0261648Z [ERROR] Please refer to C:\a\1\s\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0262122Z [ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0262542Z [ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0262923Z [ERROR] TestEngine with ID 'cucumber' failed to discover tests
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0263377Z [ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0264110Z [ERROR] TestEngine with ID 'cucumber' failed to discover tests
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0264608Z [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:701)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0265202Z [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:311)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0265801Z [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:268)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0266444Z [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1334)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0267194Z [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1167)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0267773Z [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:931)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0268337Z [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0268868Z [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:342)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0269345Z [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:330)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0269846Z [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0270356Z [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:175)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0270851Z [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000(MojoExecutor.java:76)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0271404Z [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run(MojoExecutor.java:163)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0271914Z [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute(DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0272421Z [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:160)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0272974Z [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0274647Z [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0275448Z [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0276106Z [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:118)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0276683Z [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:260)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0277011Z [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:172)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0277340Z [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:100)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0277758Z [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:821)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0278222Z [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:270)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0278668Z [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0279092Z [ERROR]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0279559Z [ERROR]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0280415Z [ERROR]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0280776Z [ERROR]    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0281056Z [ERROR]    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0281335Z [ERROR]    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0281630Z [ERROR]    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0282135Z [ERROR]    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0282339Z [ERROR] 
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0282473Z [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0282617Z [ERROR] 
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0282791Z [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0283017Z [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0283194Z [ERROR] 
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0283386Z [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0283636Z [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Please give these pages a good and careful read. It's impossible to help you because you provide too much information that is not relevant while not providing the information needed to reproduce the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: In other words, try to reproduce the problem with just the skeleton https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton and explain what you did to do so.

Comment: Sir @M.P.Korstanje I did import the above and as said locally it works , the only change I did was I have added in JunitPlatform properties = cucumber.execution.parallel.enabled=true,fixed,parallelism=2 and in yml file I have the maven task , in jobs logs get                                                                                   
[ERROR] TestEngine with ID 'cucumber' failed to discover tests
2023-03-31T15:57:21.0263377Z [ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process

Comment: If it works locally but not in CI you'll have to look at the differences between local and CI. Something is setting `cucumber.features` in CI.